# How can I optimize this for-loop?

Tags: python, loops, optimization

I need to check the occurrences of the letter `"a"` in a string `s` of size `n`.

Example:

```
s = "abcac"
n = 10
```

String to check for occurrences of letter `"a"`: `"abcacabcac"`.

Occurrences: `4`

My code works, but I need it to work faster for larger values of `n`.
What can I do to optimize this code?

```
def repeatedString(s, n):
    a_count, word_iter = 0, 0
    for i in range(n):
        if s[word_iter] == "a":
             a_count+=1

        word_iter += 1

        if word_iter == (len(s)):
            word_iter = 0

    return a_count
```

Comment: len(string.split(word)) 

I forgot python

Answer (score 2):

You only don't need to assemble the full repeated string to do it.  count the number of the specified characted in the whole string and multiple that by the number of times it will be fully repeated (`n//len(s)` times).  Add to that the number of occurrences that will appear in the last (truncated) part at the end of the repetitions (i.e. first `n%len(s)` characters)

```
def countChar(s,n,c):
    return s.count(c)*n//len(s)+s[:n%len(s)].count(c)
```

output:

```
countChar("abcac",10,"a") # 4 times in 'abcacabcac'
countChar("abcac",17,"a") # 7 times in 'abcacabcacabcacab'
```

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of times a appears in a string, s up to length n

```
s = "abcac"
n = 10
str(s*(int(n/len(s))))[:n].count('a')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
a_count = len(re.findall(r'a',s))
```

`re.findall` returns an array of all matches, and we can just get the length of it. Using a regular expression allows for greater generalization and the ability to search for more complex patterns. Debra's original answer is better for a simple string search though:

```
a_count = s.count('a')
```